# Multiple upload the files are not saved

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, vichuploaderbundle

I try to save multiple files using VichUploader Bundle.
The name of the file is well saved in database but unfortunately, the file is not moved into the correct folder.

I use Symfony 4 & VichUploaderBundle 1.8.3.

Here is my Album class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AlbumRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Album
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="album", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $photos;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

...
}
```

And now, the Photo

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PhotoRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Photo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $imageName;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="album_images", fileNameProperty="imageName")
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Album", inversedBy="photos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $album;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;
...
}
```

Ok, so, in order to use the Bundle, I wrote a DataTransformer that transform the UploadedFile into a Photo. This way, I can manipulate an array of Photo.

This PhotoTransformer is quite simple, I just want to move the files from Front to Back-end

```
class PhotoTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($value)
    {
        //We won't reverse the operation. It goes from front-end to back-end.
        return [];
    }

    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        $photos = [];
        foreach ($value as $file) {
            $photo = new Photo();
            $photo->setImageFile($file);
            $photos[] = $photo;
        }
        return $photos;
    }
}
```

And here is my AlbumType :

```
class AlbumType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        return $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
            ->add($builder->create(
                    'photos', FileType::class, [
                        'required' => false,
                        'multiple' => true
                    ]
                )->addModelTransformer(new PhotoTransformer())
            )
            ->add('button', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Create'
            ]);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I followed the rule wrote [here](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/known_issues.md#no-upload-is-triggered-when-manually-injecting-an-instance-of-symfonycomponenthttpfoundationfilefile).
The var passed to the "setImageFile" is an UploadedFile.

Yet, unfortulately, this doesn't trigger the upload on the server.

Do you know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the vich_uploader.yaml, the upload_destination was not the correct one.
So I checked at one place and the files were uploaded at another.

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

it may not have worked because you did not use the file move method?

```
$photo->move($targetDirectory, $filename);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, in fact, it was because I did not create a correct configuration file for VichUploader. The file was well uploaded but not in the correct destination folder :)